# How to refresh UI from ViewModel with ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a listbox with items bound to an ObservableCollection.

Now, from within the viewModel, I need to cause an update to the UI.
I dont have a refernce to the listbox from my view model.

If I remove or add an item from my ObservableCollection, the ui gets updated.

Based on some other logic I need to update the UI...but the ObservableCollection is the same.

How can I update the UI WITHOUT either adding or removing items from my ObservableCollection?

Thanks

Comment: what is there to update if nothing in the collection has changed?

Comment: Honestly ... we have a huge application using WPF and MVVM and we NEVER needed that. Tell us what exactly you want to update, because i'm pretty sure there are ways to accomplish that.

Comment: If you need to update the UI without modifying your collection, then perhaps you should be connecting something else in your VM to your view... not everything has to be databound via `ObservableCollection`s...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you need to change your UI because you've edited the items *in* your collection, then you should arrange for those items to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If the objects within your collection have a `PropertyChanged` event, the UI will be listening for that event from individual items. (If possible, you could also change the items in your collection to be `DependencyObjects` with `DependencyProperties`, which accomplishes the same goal.)

If you *really* need to trigger a UI update when *nothing at all* about your collection has changed, the way to do it is to manually raise the `CollectionChanged` event. This can't be done with the `ObservableCollection<>` as is, but you could derive a new collection from that class, and call the `protected OnCollectionChanged` method from within some new, `public` method.

Comment: Is there a documentation page somewhere for what exactly INotifyPropertyChanged does under the hood?

Answer (score 29):

I've had a similar issue where I wanted to change the background on an item, but obviously neither the item nor the collection changed.

It was achieved by calling:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(your_collection_name).Refresh();
```

This refreshed the view from the view model without altering the collections

Comment: In my case one Property of one object inside the list changed which influenced the view. This helped, thank you.

Comment: this didn't work for me. Do we have to specify anything else?

Comment: @MehulParmar sorry mate, haven't touched wpf in a long while and don't have my environment set up so I couldn't really answer that atm.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good case for an extension method. It hides away the implementation in case it changes in future versions, can be modified in one place, and the calling code looks simpler and less confusing.

```
public static void Refresh<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> value)
{
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(value).Refresh();
}
```

Usage:

```
myCollection.Refresh();
```

Comment: it's been 5 years, but yeah ... i'm always happy with extension methods. if you do end up doing it so often that you need one, i wonder if some logic review is in place. it did feel a bit hacky to jump through all those loops in the time.

Comment: It just feels so annoying to have to do this, having used the frontend frameworks that seamlessly bind data to markup. But we have to remember how old WPF is now. Hopefully maui fixes the amount of ceremony and code required to do this sort of thing nicely.

Comment: yes, we're way past the honeymoon period when MS said WPF and Silverlight ( cough ..cough) are going to be the future ... Also seems like latest Win 10 patch removed support for Flash ... times are a'movin ...

Comment: Thanks. I never knew CollectionViewSource could refresh an ObservableCollection. Life could have been so much easier... Still learning WPF things...